# Issue when displaying controls

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm trying to store labels in a ComboBox, with categories - something like [this](http://www.jarloo.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/grouppedCombo.png).

However, the ComboBox items are appearing like so:

[image]

This is what I've done so far:

**App.XAML**

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="groupStyle">
    <Label FontWeight="Bold" Content="{Binding Name}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

**Code Behind**

```
    ComboBox comboBox1 = new ComboBox();

    GroupStyle style = new GroupStyle();
    style.HeaderTemplate = (DataTemplate)this.FindResource("groupStyle");
    comboBox1.GroupStyle.Add(style);
    comboBox1.DisplayMemberPath = "Item";
    ObservableCollection<CategoryItem<Label>> items = new ObservableCollection<CategoryItem<string>>();

    Label label = new Label();
    TextBlock block = new TextBlock();
    block.Text = "Text";
    label.Content = block;

    items.Add(new CategoryItem<Label> { Category = "Category", Item = label });

    CollectionViewSource cvs = new CollectionViewSource();
    cvs.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Category"));
    cvs.Source = items;

    Binding b = new Binding();
    b.Source = cvs;
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(comboBox1, ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, b);

public class CategoryItem<T>
{
    public T Item { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `ItemContainerStyle`. However you may have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773048/wpf-combobox-how-to-you-utilise-a-generic-itemcontainerstyle-with-binding)

**App.Xaml**

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="groupStyle">
    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
</DataTemplate>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}"  x:Key="comboBoxItemStyle">
    <Setter Property="Template" >
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Label Background="Red" Content="{Binding Item}"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Code behind:**

```
 ComboBox comboBox1 = new ComboBox();

 GroupStyle style = new GroupStyle();
 style.HeaderTemplate = (DataTemplate)this.FindResource("groupStyle");
 comboBox1.GroupStyle.Add(style);
 comboBox1.DisplayMemberPath = "Item";

 // Here is what you are looking for
 comboBox1.ItemContainerStyle = (Style)this.FindResource("comboBoxItemStyle");


 ObservableCollection<CategoryItem<string>> items = new ObservableCollection<CategoryItem<string>>();

 CollectionViewSource cvs = new CollectionViewSource();
 cvs.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Category"));
 cvs.Source = items;

 Binding b = new Binding();
 b.Source = cvs;
 BindingOperations.SetBinding(
           comboBox1, ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, b);
```

Comment: The only issue now seems to be that when I mouse over the labels, there is no blue border around them like when hovering over a ComboBoxItem

Comment: I think, you should define some triggers in the `ControlTemplate` but I'm not good enough in that case. I edited my post and you may get some idea from the link which I provide.